# web scraping a website with python shows no results

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, url

i'm new to web scraping , i'm trying to write a code to scrape a website, i tried aliexpress because it is said that it's scraper friendly , still it doesn't show any results , when i run it , i get "no products were found" i asked chatgpt , it added a few lines for timeouts and exceptions and such , but still no results , it doesn't get the urls , how do i fix this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

base_url = "https://ar.aliexpress.com/?gatewayAdapt=glo2ara"
urls = [base_url]
products = []

while len(urls) != 0:
    current_url = urls.pop()

    try:
        response = requests.get(current_url, timeout=20)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        link_elements = soup.select("a[href]")

        for link_element in link_elements:
            url = link_element['href']
            if base_url in url:
                urls.append(url)

                product = {}
                product["url"] = current_url

                # Corrected selector to target the image element
                image_element = soup.select_one(".product img")
                if image_element:
                    product["image"] = image_element["src"]
                else:
                    product["image"] = "Image not found"

                title_element = soup.select_one(".product_title")
                if title_element:
                    product["title"] = title_element.text 
                else:
                    product["title"] = "Title not found"

                # Add other fields as needed (e.g., price)

                products.append(product)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while processing {current_url}: {e}")

    time.sleep(0.1)
if products:
# Print the list of products
     print(products)

# Writing to CSV file
     csv_file_path = 'products.csv'
     with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
         writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=products[0].keys())

    # Writing header
         writer.writeheader()

    # Writing rows
         writer.writerows(products)
 
     print(f"Data written to {csv_file_path}")
else:
    print("No products found.")
```

Comment: Since scraping is, by definition, not using a public API there is more than the usual amount of trial and error as you discover the structure of the document and how to extract the parts you want. You should use a debugger and peel the onion one layer at a time as part of your debugging strategy. Getting no output is a sign that the document is *not* structured the way you think it is.

Comment: the usual suspects in web scraping are lack of headers and lack of cookies. try to set a user agent header first. if it doesn't work use the `session` in `requests` module

Comment: Another common issues is sites that generate content dynamically using javascript. This content will be invisible to a script using `requests` to fetch content.